# How to draw a grouped barplot of two dataframes?

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart

I have two things I want to compare:

1. Data from a questionaire that I collected myself.
2. The distribution of the norm sample from the people that have developed the questionaire.

Here is a barplot of my data:

```
ggplot(myData) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = DepriSymptoms, y = ..prop..,  group = 1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  labs(y = "Participant Count",
       x = "Symptoms",
       title = "Depression Symptom Severity")
```

[Barplot of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEWLj.png)

I don't have the actual data of the norm sample, I only know the precentages:

- none: 70%
- suspected: 9%
- light: 15%
- medium: 4%
- severe: 1%

My goal is a grouped ggplot2 barplot that looks similar to this:

[Mockup of grouped barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ2qT.png)

One color would be my data, the other color would be the norm sample.

Here is my Question: *What is the best way to get ggplot2 to draw the bars for the norm sample, since I don't have the data?*

I thought of creating a new dataframe with "fake" data that has the right percentages and using two geom_bar layers, but now they are on top of each other and I can't use a fill variable to group by, since they are from different dataframes.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = myData, mapping = aes(x = DepriSymptoms, y = ..prop..,  group = 1), alpha = 0.5, fill = 'blue') +
  geom_bar(data = fakeData, mapping = aes(x = DepriSymptoms, y = ..prop..,  group = 2), alpha = 0.5, fill = 'red') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

I'm sure there has to be a more elegant way to do this.

I hope I managed to explain my situation somewhat understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I got from your question is that you have one type of data for which you have individual cases, and one type of data for which you have proportions. These data should be represented on the same bar graph.

Since I don't have a sample of your data I'll use a standard dataset and reshape it a bit to reflect your case.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Suppose df1 is the equivalent of DepriSymptoms
df1 <- mpg[mpg$year == 1999,]

# And we'll shape df2 to be similar to DepriNorm (proportion data)
df2 <- mpg[mpg$year == 2008,]
df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(class) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n))

head(df2)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   class          n   prop
#>   <chr>      <int>  <dbl>
#> 1 2seater        3 0.0256
#> 2 compact       22 0.188 
#> 3 midsize       21 0.179 
#> 4 minivan        5 0.0427
#> 5 pickup        17 0.145 
#> 6 subcompact    16 0.137
```

So in the data above we can count the cases in `df1` but must use the `prop` column in `df2`. You can totally use the two layers approach, but you'd have to be mindful that layers can't see into other layers and thus the dodging from the bar groups is absent. Two tips here:

- You can use `geom_col()` as a shortcut for `geom_bar(..., stat = "identity")`, so it will not try to count your proportion data.
- You can use `position = position_nudge(x = ...)` to offset your bars so that they appear grouped, even though they are on different layers. You'd also have to change the width of the bars.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(class)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(prop), group = 1, fill = "A"),
           width = 0.4, position = position_nudge(0.22)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = prop, fill = "B"), data = df2,
           width = 0.4, position = position_nudge(-0.22))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>